# Grails - How to check, if a link is pointed to correct location using Geb?

Tags: geb

I have a link `<a herf="redirect_url" class="class_name">link</a>` that is pointed to some page. How can i check if, the link is pointed to correct location using Geb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work

`$("a.class_name").attr("href") == "redirect_url"`